# Is a compact set holomorphically convex in a domain holomorphically convex?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Suppose a compact set $K$ has the property that there is a domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that: $$ \{z \in \mathbb{C}^n : |f(z)| \le ||f||_K \: \forall f \in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}^n)\} \cap \Omega= \bar K \cap \Omega = K$$ does it fallow that $K=\bar K$?

Comment: What is really the hypothesis? $\overline{K}=A=K$ implies $\overline{K}=K$ by transitivity and then $K=\overline{K}$ by symmetry.

Comment: @arts first = should be in bracket (it is definition of $\bar K$).